# How to define proper constraints for scrollview to work effectively

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

My storyboard layout is simple as shown in the attached image. I am assuming that the body text could span from a single line to multiple lines. Considering the case of multiple lines, I expect the content to scroll so that the button can be clickable. However, with the constraints I have set, the scroll view does not scroll. What constraints should I change in order to get the desired effect? Thank you.

[image: constraints defined]

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in scrolling, it will be very helpful if this problem is solved. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You want body text in center if there is single line text ?

Comment: @Sujal if you want demo than i will give you

Comment: Do not use scroll view directly, instead use UITableView or UICollectionView subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to using `UIScrollView`: You must have a "chain" of constraints to allow auto-layout to determine the `.contentSize` of the scroll view.

Step-by-step (I like to set background colors during layout, to make it easy to see the bounds / frames of the elements)...

Add a `UIScrollView` (Cantaloupe color) to your view controller, and constrain it by 20-pts all the way around (just so we can see where it is):

[image]

Add a `UIView` as your `ContentView` (Strawberry color) as a subview of the scroll view. Give it equal Height and Width constraints to the scroll view, and top / leading / trailing / bottom constraints all set to `0`:

[image]

Add your `Title` `UILabel` (Yellow background). Constrain it `Top: 30 / Leading: 50 / Trailing: 50`. Add your `Body` `UILabel` (Yellow background). Constrain its Top to the Title label's Bottom (I used `200`), and `Leading: 10 / Trailing: 10`. Add your `UIButton` (Light Gray background). Constrain its Top to the Body label's Bottom (I used `50`), and `Leading: 50 / Trailing: 50`:

[image]

So far, nothing special, and you won't get any scrolling...

Next, add ***another*** Bottom constraint of `0` to the `ContentView`, and change the first Bottom constraint to be `>= 0` and set the Priority of the new Bottom constraint to `250`:

[image]

This will (after a couple more steps) allow `ContentView` to expand / collapse based on its content, as well as control the `.contentSize` of the scroll view.

The next step is to tell the `Button` to determine the Height of the `ContentView` - so add a Bottom constraint of `30` to the button (which will be equal to the `Top: 30` we gave to the title label):

[image]

Of course, that's *not quite* what we want. It stretches the height of the button because we set a *height constraint* on the `ContentView`. So... **delete** the height constraint from the `ContentView`:

[image]

The result is that the `ContentView` height will shrink to fit 30-pts below the bottom of the button.

If you add some more text to the `Body` label (assuming it is set to `Number of Lines; 0`), you will see the `Body` label expand and "push down" the button, which in turn "pushes down" the bottom of `ContentView`:

[image]

If you add enough text to `Body` to push the button below the bottom of the scroll view - either in IB or via code - it will now scroll vertically.

Hope that's clear... please ask if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you, it is working. This is the result I was trying to obtain. Could you please tell me why we have to use two bottom constraints and change the priority?

Comment: The 2nd bottom constraint - equal to `0` with `Priority 250` is not, as far as I know, strictly necessary... If you set up the constraints via  code, it it can be skipped. I think it is only necessary for Interface Builder... because the content is dynamic, IB doesn't completely "believe" there are enough constraints to satisfy the `contentSize` of the scroll view. Without it, IB will continue to show the red "Constraint Ambiguity" error / warning, but auto-layout will not complain at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your constraints proper for scroll view there are certain way you have to follow.please find below steps.

1.Add scroll view to super view.After adding scroll view add subview to scroll view as shown in the image.
This view will have same x,y co ordinate as well as same height and width as of scroll view.
Please refer below image to understand hierarchy.

[image]

You will find the red warning because we have not yet added any constraints.

2. Now its time to apply some constraints.
   Refer image bellow and add top, bottom, leading and trailing to scroll view.

[image]

3. Now add same top, bottom, leading and trailing  to scroll view’s child view. Refer below image.
   [image]
4. Now is a real trick.Hold both scroll and view in one and give both of them equal width,equal height constraints as shown in below image.

[image]

Your constraints are almost set.now depending upon your contains stretch the view.
When you increase the view’s height after that click on update constraints.

The last thing you need to do is change scroll view’s bottom constraints value.It will be some negative value.Replace it with 0.follow below screenshot

[image]

Please update if it works

Comment: Appreciate your effort. I followed till step 4. Then you have mentioned to stretch the view but the thing is the content of the view is unknown prior. Based on api call, the text body will be obtained which can be of any length. How do I make the scroll work without stretching the view?

Comment: I will suggest to use table view in that case where you don’t know how much will be your contentsize.. otherwise you have to maintain it programmatically only constraints will not served the purpose.